# Actionscript 3 XML get node name

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

This is my XML, I want to dynamically get the node/tag name (ex: wa, or, ca).

```
<root>
  <wa title='someValue'>
  </wa>
  <or title='val'>
    <data >ss</data>
    <data>sss</data>
  </or>
  <ca title='val'>
    <data>xyz</data>  
  </ca>
</root>
```

the following is working but it gives only root node name

```
for each (var item:XML in xml) {
  trace (item.name());
}
```

the following one is going thought each element under root but not giving the node name

```
for each(var itemData:XML in xml.elements()) {
   trace ("itemCount " + itemData.name);
}
```

Please advise to get the node name under root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**name** is a function. You forgot to use `()` :

```
for each(var itemData:XML in xml.elements()) {
   trace ("itemCount " + itemData.name());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `localName()` method return node name only .

```
for each(var itemData:XML in xml.elements()) 
{
    trace ("itemCount " + itemData.localName()); 
}
```

`name()` return full-qualified name like if xml with namespace like

```
xmlns:xpl="http://www.example.com/uri/"
<xpl:ca title='val'>
   <data>xyz</data>
 </xpl:ca>
```

o/p : `http://www.example.com/uri/:ca`